# Sed not working as intended

Tags: sed

I would like to use this script with the intention of replacing all instances of the letter *Q* within a file with the contents of the file "question.txt". Instead what happens is that all the instances of *Q* in the file disappear and the contents of "question.txt" are printed at the bottom of the new file.

Any ideas?

```
sed -i.bkp '/Q/{
s/Q//g
r /Users/ericbrotto/Desktop/question.txt
}' Commision.txt
```

**EDIT 1**

I'm trying to find out what version I have, but keep on getting this:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Post a sample input file and the output you get, and tell us what sed version you're using.

Comment: I can reproduce it with `GNU sed-Version 4.2.1`, without the content of 'question.txt' printed at the bottom of the new file.

Comment: How does one find out which version they have? I did sed -V and it didn't work :(

Comment: I reproduced this as well with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`. A simple set of test files where the search string was in the middle of the file left the read file at the end, not in place of the searched string.

Comment: @Eric: `sed --version`

Comment: @Caleb, etc. Please see my EDIT 1.

Comment: @Eric: Try `man sed` or `sed -h`, `sed --help` etc. However I think the clue that you're on a macbook using OSX is enough. Besides I've replicated this on GNU sed on Linux.

Comment: Dope! @Caleb, I guess I should have specified my OS. Does this mean there is no hope for me in resolving this? I used man and got a bunch of info, but couldn't see which version I have except at one point it says HISTORY
     A sed command, written by L. E. McMahon, appeared in Version 7 AT&T UNIX.

Comment: @Eric: By "replicated" I mean I have the same problem, so it's not just your version that's broken, it's something we are doing wrong. I don't know enough `sed` to say how to do this correctly, but I'm sure there is a way. Stay tuned for answers.

Comment: @userunknown and Eric: could you guys try [this script](http://pastebin.com/XU6VVncc) and report where the read-file got inserted?

Comment: @userunknown I have no idea what the difference between this test script which seems to work fine and the test I rand the other day which I remember failing is. If you have a failing example can you please post? (Obviously the issue of delete vs. insert is a different problem, the question is are the commands in the example giving the expected results with the data file embedded in the source?

Comment: Here's one way of finding the version: (Note: I use Ubuntu) `$ dpkg -l | grep ' sed '` ` ii sed 4.2.1-6 The GNU sed stream editor`

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found the reason why.

If I put some blank after the filename, a filename with trailing blanks is searched. I can reproduce the problem this way:

Sources:

```
cat q.dat
Q
Not q
And Q again
And again not


cat kuh.dat 
Die dumme
Kuh
```

Working example with filename 'kuh.dat':

```
sed '/Q/{
s/Q//g
r kuh.dat
}' q.dat

Die dumme
Kuh
Not q
And  again
Die dumme
Kuh
And again not
```

Now the failing example, with 'kuh.dat '.

```
sed '/Q/{
s/Q//g
r kuh.dat 
}' q.dat

Not q
And  again
And again not
```

Since the filename isn't quoted, it is a great surprise for me, that the blank at the filename-end is recognized. And it isn't visible in the shell, so I searched for a long time without success, where the difference between the two examples is.

Comment: Good idea. It doesn't explain why there'd be a copy of `question.txt` at the bottom of the output though.

Comment: Ah, yes, I had forgotten about that. And I have never reproduced it. Did somebody reproduce that?